# Function not accepting any parameter

Tags: scala

I have a function which does not accept any parameters and returns a partial function.

```
def receive:PartialFunction[Any,Unit]={
case "hello"=>println("Got it 1")
case 123=>println("Got it 2")
case true=>println("Got it 3")
}
receive("hello")
```

I am unable to understand this function invocation syntax. How is the string being passed to the receive function and how is the case function executing?

However, I am unable to understand the below code as well:

```
def receive():PartialFunction[Any,Unit]={
case "hello"=>println("Got it 1")
case 123=>println("Got it 2")
case true=>println("Got it 3")
}
val y=receive()
y("hello")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. An anonymous partial function like `{ case ... }` is short for

   ```
   new PartialFunction[Any, Unit] {
     def isDefinedAt(x: Any) = x match {
       case "hello" => true
       case 123 => true
       case true => true
       case _ => false
     }

     def apply(x: Any) = x match {
       case "hello" => println("Got it 1")
       case 123 => println("Got it 2")
       case true => println("Got it 3")
     }
   }
   ```

   (`[Any, Unit]` comes from the expected type in this case.)
2. Because `receive` is not a method with parameters, `receive("hello")` is short for `receive.apply("hello")`.

Comment: can you explain why you have added case _=>false in isDefinedAt()? Does scala automatically add that, if no case _ is present in the case statements? Can you give me a link about that? Thanks again!

Comment: Because `isDefinedAt` has to be defined everywhere. Just see the documentation http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/PartialFunction.html for what it means.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to explain second part of your question. As you can see there is small difference between two definitions of receive method, one with parenthesis and other without. As it was said in previous answer, call:

```
val func: Any => Any = ???
func(42)
```

Is transformed by scala parser to:

```
func.apply(42)
```

The same holds true for partial functions (and object of any type having apply method defined). So your invocations are rewrtitten to something like this:
First:

```
val y = receive()
y.apply("hello")
```

Second:

```
receive.apply("hello")
```

Maybe you can see the difference now? You cannot write receive.apply, when receive have (empty, but existing) parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.